# Pandas Dataframe append one row at a time into CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

Im trying to send a pandas dataframe into a csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import os

case_array = [['2017042724', '05/18/2017'], ['2017042723', '05/18/2017'], ['2017042722', '05/18/2017'], ['2017042721', '05/18/2017']]

filename = 'case_array.csv'
path = "C:\shares\folder"
fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

for case_row in case_array:
    df = pd.DataFrame(case_row)
    try:
        with open(fullpath, 'w+') as f:
            df.to_csv(f, header=False)
            print('Success')
    except:
        print('Unable to Write CSV')

try:
    df = pd.read_csv(fullpath)
    print(df)
except:
    print('Unable to Read CSV')
```

but its inserting each row as a column, inserting a header column (was set to False) and overwriting the previous insertion:

```
0  2017042721
1  05/18/2017
```

If I insert the entire array it will insert rows without the header row. (This is the correct result I want) The issue is the script I writing I need to insert each row at a time.

How do I get pandas dataframe to insert a row instead of a column?

edit1

like this:

```
 0            1
 2017042721  05/18/2017
 2017042723  05/18/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to loop over the array to do it. You can make a dataframe out of the array and have it written to a csv using [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
case_array = [['2017042724', '05/18/2017'], ['2017042723', '05/18/2017'], ['2017042722', '05/18/2017'], ['2017042721', '05/18/2017']]

df=pd.DataFrame(case_array)
df.to_csv(fullpath, header=False)
```

**EDIT**

If you must iterate over the array you below code:

```
for case_row in case_array:
    df = pd.DataFrame(case_row).T
    try:
        with open(fullpath, 'a') as f:
            df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
            print('Success')
    except:
        print('Unable to Write CSV')
```

Comment: I understand I dont have to, but I need to for the script Im writing